# Which was the first story featuring time loops?

Tags: history-of

In  [*Re:Zero* 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re:Zero_%E2%88%92_Starting_Life_in_Another_World):

> Subaru Natsuki is a NEET who is suddenly summoned to a fantasy-like world. Just after arriving, he is killed while trying to help a young elf, just to revive some hours in the past. After dying some times, he realizes that he has the power to turn back time after his death.

In [*Source Code* 2011](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0945513/plotsummary?ref_=tt_stry_pl#synopsis):

> U.S. Army Aviation pilot Captain Colter Stevens repeatedly experiences the last eight minutes of another person's life to identify the bomber in a terrorist attack in order to prevent a second, nuclear attack on Chicago

And in [*Groundhog Day* (1993)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107048/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1):

> A weatherman finds himself inexplicably living the same day over and over again.

Which was the first story featuring time loops, or a character living the same period of time again and again?

Comment: Please don't create tags for every little concept; only create them when they're needed and they're not really needed here.

Comment: TNG's "Time Squared" featured the Enterprise trapped in a time loop, that aired April 3, 1989.

Comment: @Edlothiad not sure, I havent watched/ read all the examples he mentions and he didnt describe them, he only mentioned they had "infinite time loops". The most upvoted answer has an example which describes a room where time flows different, it looks like the room of spirit and time of Dragon Ball , which isnt a time loop in the sense I'm asking

Comment: @Edlothiad ok, reading the explanation in one of the comments it seems it is the same question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1904**:  The Science Fiction Encyclopedia [Time Loop](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/time_loop) page lists [*The Defence of Duffer's Drift*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Defence_of_Duffer%27s_Drift) by Ole Luk-Oie:

> Successive dreams as by [Lieutenant] Backsight Forethought reiterate a Boer War skirmish with steadily increasing understanding and improvement of small-unit tactics against a larger force.

It's also mentioned on the TVTropes ["Groundhog Day" Loop](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GroundhogDayLoop) page:

> *The Defence of Duffer's Drift* uses the dream variant as a framing device—not dreams within dreams, but a sequence of dreams all depicting the same scenario where the protagonist must command his platoon of fifty men to defend a strategic riverbed crossing in The Second Boer War. To prevent him from "cheating", the protagonist cannot remember the exact circumstances from dream to dream (enemy force composition and direction, et cetera), but he can and does learn general tactical lessons.

Comment: I am reminded on the much later (1970) story " Maverick" by  Gordon R. Dickson (see http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?59728 ) in which a character has a series of artificial dreams of successively refined solutions to a social problem. This is one of the stories in *Five Fates*.

Comment: You might want to post this answer in the found duplicate question because the lower date they describe it's from 1932

Answer (score 3):

The 1941 story ["By His Bootstraps"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/By_His_Bootstraps) by Robert A. Heinlein involves a time loop, in which causation is circular, and in winch one character experiences the same events from three different points of view. It does not involve an apparently endless repetition of the same events, but it an early time loop story, and perhaps the first story with circular causation.

Comment: Is there any reason to think _The Defence of Duffer's Drift_ (1904) as mentioned in a previous answer doesn't match the criteria? If not then as this is newer and posted afterwards I don't really think this is an answer to the question looking for the _first_ work featuring this.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I would say that *The Defence of Duffer's Drift* is not really a time loop, nor is it SF. It is a book in which a situation is repeated with variations, via a dream mechanism. BTW it is referred to by name in one of  Elizabeth Moon's "Vatta's War" series, I had no idea it was a real book until I read this answer and followed the link. In any case BHB is one of the earliest time-loop stories, perhaps the first to be actual SF, and so worth mention here in my view.

Comment: This may not be the _first_ time loop story, but it is the _only one you ever need to read_.  Heinlein retired the trophy.  (For serious time loop stories.  For comedy time loop stories the award goes to Lem for one of his Prix the Pilot tales, forget which one.)

Answer (score 2):

- Dead of Night (1945) https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/DeadOfNight

> The main character, Craig, is stuck in a country house with people he recognises from his nightmares and is compelled to kill everyone, just like he does every time in the nightmares. He then wakes up, relieved that this was All Just a Dream, but receives a phone call from one of the persons in his nightmare to drive over to the very same country house, where the same sequence of events starts to play out once again.

In television, maybe Doctor Who.

- Doctor Who, "Carnival of Monsters" aired Jan. 1973, https://broadwcast.org/index.php/Carnival_of_Monsters